# remove all html tags in tinyeditor WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, tinyeditor

is there have anyway to remove all html tags when we paste something into WYSIWYG editor.

[to tinyeditor](http://www.scriptiny.com/2010/02/javascript-wysiwyg-editor/)

Comment: There is an option to switch between `wysiwyg` and `source`. Why not paste your `html` tagged content in `source` view ? [Try Here](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinyeditor/)

Comment: am using default settings and source. so dats why i pasted original link of this editor. i just want to know how i can strip all html pasted contents.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanna reset content body after you post something:

editor.e.body.innerHTML = ""

I hope it can help you